# Function in JavaScript is not called when loading new page by clicking href url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery Mobile to create a web app.I have a problem with the href link and my javascript code.
Here is my javascript code in my `index.html` and `curate.html`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("Hello!");
});
```

In the html code, it's just code of a navigation bar:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="curate.html">curate</a></li>
</ul>
```

So the problem is: when I on the home page, for instance, click the curate link to the curate page, the alert will not pop out. It seems the function is not called in javascript. However, it works if I reload the curate page. Same problem from the curate page to the home page.

The problem will be fixed if I change the html code as

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="gotoCurate()">curate</a></li>
</ul>
```

and add the js code in index.html:

```
function gotoCurate() { 
    window.location="curate.html"
}
```

Similar to the curate page.

I guess maybe when using href, the page isn't really load. I add `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">` in the head but it doesn't work. For some reasons I would like to use href to direct between the pages. So does anyone know how can i fix the problem while keeping the href links?

Thanks!

Comment: you missed the ; at end the end, that is $(document).ready(function(){
   alert("Hello!");
});

Comment: Thx! It was a mistake when typing in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by jQuery Mobile. Here is the detail: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

Answer (score 4):

You need to change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert("Hello!");
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert("Hello!")});
```

I'd also break the structure onto different lines, it's much more clear for when you may want to improve the system in the future.

Comment: Thanks very much James, but i think it was a typing mistake I made here, not in my real code.

Comment: No problem, have you got it working yet? It could be a mistake elsewhere in your JavaScript code that's preventing the $(document).ready() block from being executed.

Comment: Not yet. It is not executed if I load the page by clicking the href link.But if I refresh the page, then $document.ready() is executed.

Comment: That's so strange... I'll have a think and get back to you.

Comment: I can't find or think of any jQuery bugs that may be causing the problem, does the page contain any more JavaScript/jQuery code?

Comment: @JamesWright I think I included the js/jQuery library I needed. I was thinking the problem was on the href link, which made the browser to just load the content without calling the function that was supposed to called when the entire page was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

to see what's going wrong when developing with javascript, you should use developer console of your navigator, it help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try including this  `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>`

[This](http://www.roseindia.net/ajax/jquery/jquery-Hello-world-Alert.shtml) example should help.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The difference between mine and the example is I used hrel link and he used button input.I do think there is a problem with the hrel link

Comment: You need the JQuery Library. Only include wont work. Please [Download](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

Comment: @nimish Why are you referencing an outdated version of jQuery?

Comment: @JamesWright Not really.. I was highlighting the inclusion of the JS Library from the Example which I had posted a link to.
I am sorry if it was perceived as I was recommending adding the 1.4.2 lib. Basically in my next response I have given a link to the download location where the latest library can be found.
Only problem I could see in his implementation was the missed library inclusion.

Comment: @nimish Extremely sorry for jumping to that conclusion, I just get very pedantic about people using out-of-date software for no reason!